# retain NA in custom winsorization function withs apply

Tags: r

I am attempting to winsorize a data frame with a lot of NA entries, and I need to retain the NA entries after winsorization.  The columns within the data frame that require winsorization on fine on the lower end (i.e. small values), but require some winsorization on the upper end (i.e. large values).  I have created a function that almost does the job, but I can't seem to get the function to return NA entries where they occur.  
 Here is an example.

```
# vector with an NA entry & upper-end value needs winsorization
a <- c(1:3,NA,90) 

# my function
winsor <- function(x)
{ y <- quantile(x,probs=.95,na.rm=T)
sapply(x, function(x) {
if ( x>=y ){
x <- y
}
else { x <- x}
})

# returned vector after apply winsor to my object, a.
z <- as.data.frame(winsor(a))
```

The result I get when doing this gives the following error:

> Error in if (x >= y) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

But it nevertheless returns the following vector (which is what I want, expect it does not return the NA entry as needed).

```
a
1.000
2.000
3.000
85.824
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as well as an extension to operationalize this function to an entire data frame.  Hopefully this all makes sense.  This is my very fist post (and hopefully my example is reproducible!).

Comment: Probably something like `winsor <- function(x) x[x <= quantile(x,probs=.95,na.rm=T) | is.na(x)]` will suffice for what you are doing. However, winsorizing typically involves trimming both the upper and lower parts of the distribution.

Comment: True enough.  Many definitions of winsorization refer to adjustments/trimming at both tails.  However, in my case, the data I'm working with requires no adjustment on the lower end -- just the high-end.  Given this, I'm not sure what the adequate technical definition would be in this case.  For what it's worth, I have since found the following to work pretty well using ifelse():

Comment: Whoops.  Here is the code using if else().                                                      a <- as.data.frame(ifelse(a>quantile(a,probs=.95,na.rm=T), quantile(a,probs=.95,na.rm=T),a))

Answer (score 0):

winsor function needs an `}` in the end. I took the liberty and tweaked the code:

```
winsor <- function(x){ 
  y <- quantile(x,probs=.95,na.rm=T)
  sapply(x, function(x) {
   if(!is.na(x)){
      if(x>=y ){
       x <- y
    }
     else { x <- x}
  }
 }) 
}

z<-data.frame(winsor=as.numeric(unlist(winsor(a))))
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirements of retaining NA's after winsorization

Comment: Like Michael Kirchner, I also do not find that this retains NA's after winsorization.  In fact, I tried several iterations somewhat similar to what agerom has provided, but couldn't get it to work.  Hence the question.